# Suspend broken: pm-suspend fails due to /sys/power/* being a Read-only file system

Tags: 14.04, power-management, suspend, apparmor

My System 76 laptop running 14.04 won't suspend. Running `sudo pm-suspend` fails with the following in `/var/log/pm-suspend.log`:

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend:
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq: 23: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq: cannot create cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Read-only file system
...
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq: 23: /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq: cannot create cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Read-only file system
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/94cpufreq suspend suspend: Returned exit code 2.`
```

If I disable all `sleep.d` scripts that attempt to write to `/sys`, it still ends up failing:

```
/usr/sbin/pm-suspend: 321: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend: cannot create /sys/power/state: Read-only file system
```

sysfs looks perfectly normal to me:

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)

# ls -al /sys/power
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Aug 14 10:25 .
dr-xr-xr-x 13 root root    0 Aug 14 09:47 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 10:45 disk
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 11:05 image_size
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 11:05 pm_async
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 11:05 pm_freeze_timeout
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 11:05 pm_print_times
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 11:05 pm_test
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 11:05 pm_trace
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 11:05 pm_trace_dev_match
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 11:05 reserved_size
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 11:05 resume
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 10:25 state
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Aug 14 11:05 wakeup_count
```

I always use sudo or su to root when trying the command. Even trying to manually use the kernel's test power management interface fails:

```
root@...:~# echo core > /sys/power/pm_test
-su: /sys/power/pm_test: Read-only file system
```

Kernel: 3.13.0-33-generic #58-Ubuntu
All packages are up to date.

Comment: Uninstalling apparmor fixes the permission error, but I need it installed for docker. Even without apparmor installed pm-suspend only works for 50 seconds before it wakes back up.